# Saving a plot in Octave with a transparent background

Tags: octave

I've plotted some GPS tracks and heading vectors using Octave.

I'd like to overlay the plot on a satellite image, but when I save the plot it has a white background. Is there a way to save it with a transparent background?

Answer (score 4):

I think using print with the "pngalpha" device does what you want, e.g.:

```
print(gcf,'-dpngalpha', 'myplot.png');
```

This is poorly documented unfortunately. I browsed the source code extensively to find a way to hack/patch octave to do this, only to find out this was already possible.

Comment: I generated a figure this way, in Octave 5.1.0.
Then in xnview it appears white background, as opposed to other pngs I have with transparent background.
Adding the image in Powerpoint, images below it did not show.
So I conclude this is not working.

Comment: My original answer was from 2014. I have no idea what Octave version I used, but I suppose Gnuplot was the default graphics toolkit back then. It is still available as an alternative graphics toolkit in Octave 5.1.0. Try setting it before creating the figure: `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')`. I tried it just now with a 2D plot. The plot area itself is white and not transparent, but area around that is transparent. However the background in 3D plots is fully transparent. Try e.g. `sombrero` with the gnuplot toolkit.

Comment: Good feedback. I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512909/2707864) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64522033/2707864) on this as well.