# Printing / saving a plot as a png file with an alpha channel issue in Octave

Tags: image, octave

How can I print / save a plot as a png file with an alpha channel?

I tried
[Saving a plot in Octave with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438777/saving-a-plot-in-octave-with-transparent-background)

**I'm using Octave 4.2.2, Ubuntu 18.04 64bit, and graphics_toolkit fltk**

```
t = [0:0.01:2*pi]; x = sin (t);
plot (t, x);
set(gcf, 'Position',  [10, 10, 500, 500]);
print(gcf,'-dpngalpha', 'myplot.png');
```

> I get an error
> error: print: unknown device pngalpha
> error: called from
> **print_parse_opts** at line 265 column 5
> print at line 316 column 8

Please note: Octave is on 5.2 and this issue has a work around below...

Comment: Which graphics tollkit on which OS?

Comment: @Andy I'm using Octave 4.2.2, Ubuntu 18.04 64bit, and graphics_toolkit fltk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512909/2707864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(update: also see Sancho's nice answer here: [Have a transparent background in a plot exported from Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64460791/4183191) )

---

In general, adding transparency in octave is still not fully supported. My advice would be to produce your images as normal, and use an external tool to add transparency (which you could call from within octave via the `system` function, if you'd like it to be part of a script).

The imagemagick suite can do what you want via the convert command, e.g.

```bash
convert  myplot.png  -fuzz 50%  -transparent white  myplot_transparent.png
```

(taken from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=41925&sid=ef6deefbcb2ec099ef268d8613052780#p41925))

If you'd like to produce many 'layers', some of which have transparency, and then overlay them (which presumably is what you want the transparency for in the first place), you can also do this via imagemagick via:

```bash
convert  bottomlayer.png  toplayer.png  -compose over  -composite out.png
```

So a complete example in octave might look something like this:

```matlab
t = [0:0.01:2*pi];

% Create bottom layer (no transparency needed)
plot (t, sin(t), 'r', 'linewidth', 3);
set(gcf, 'Position',  [10, 10, 500, 500]);
axis([-1, 7, -1, 1]);
set(gca, 'Position',  [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]);
saveas(gcf, 'bottom.png');

% Create top layer, and make transparent (via imagemagick)
plot (t, cos(t), 'g', 'linewidth', 3);
set(gcf, 'Position',  [10, 10, 500, 500]);
axis([-1, 7, -1, 1]);
axis off;
set(gca, 'Position',  [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]);
saveas(gcf, 'top.png');
system('convert top.png  -fuzz 10% -transparent white top.png');

% Combine layers
system('convert bottom.png top.png -compose over -composite result.png');

%Visualise result in octave
imshow result.png
```

Resulting image:

[image]

Comment: I wonder why you say "adding transparency in octave is still not fully supported". 
It would be interesting to know what version you were referring to.
And if there is any example that could be quoted for this lack of full support.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio it's a slowly implemented feature, but lack of full transparency support for particular areas is mentioned in a few places in the documentation: e.g. see [here](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Axes-Properties.html) and [here](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Image-Properties.html)

Comment: I see transparency is not implemented for image or axes objects.
But writing images to file with alpha channel seems to work fine, at least in my 5.1.0.
This is not a minor difference, possibly worth clarifying in the answer... will add it to an answer.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio better yet, I added a reference to your post just now :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you want to simply generate a file with a transparent background, or you want to handle the more general case of an arbitrary alpha channel for your image file.

Fortunately, it seems Octave can handle the second case as well.
As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927098/printing-saving-a-plot-as-a-png-file-with-an-alpha-channel-issue-in-octave/58932458?noredirect=1#comment114088355_58932458),
transparency is not implemented for image or axes objects, but writing images to file with an alpha channel seems to work fine, at least in version 5.1.0.

So this would produce a transparent alpha channel for white (`tcolor = [255 255 255]`)

```
im = print(gcf, '-RGBImage');
tcolor = [255 255 255];
alpha(:,:) = 255 * ( 1 - (im(:,:,1) == tcolor(1)) .* (im(:,:,2) == tcolor(2)) .* (im(:,:,3) == tcolor(3)) );
imwrite(im, 'myplot.png', 'Alpha', alpha);
```