# Have a transparent background in a plot exported from Octave

Tags: plot, background, octave, transparency

I am using portable Octave 5.1.0 under Win 10.
I mean to write a plot to png with transparent background.

Disclaimer:
This question is similar to the two linked below.
I opted [asking the present different question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402242/dr-strangedupe-ask-a-question-with-the-same-objective-but-different-text-body) since I am adding further relevant information (by the same token, question #2 below was not a dupe of #1).

This is what I found:

1. `print(gcf,'-dpngalpha', 'myplot.png');`, suggested in [Saving a plot in Octave with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438777/saving-a-plot-in-octave-with-transparent-background), [does not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438777/saving-a-plot-in-octave-with-transparent-background#comment113980369_23824542).
   It is remarkable that *I did not find documentation on this option*.
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58932458/2707864) has a couple of issues for me: 1) for some unknown reason `convert` does nothing.   2) The requirement of an external package makes it cumbersome. For instance, I cannot simply send my Octave code to someone else for him to use it.
3. Option `svgconvert` is the only [official documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html) I found.
   But it would not apply to a png, e.g.
4. [`imwrite`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Loading-and-Saving-Images.html) seems to have the capability to write with transparency, but I couldn't find a way to transform a plot into and image suitable for `imwrite`.
   (See also [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)).
   Perhaps this is a possible route...

**Is there any option available in Octave?**

**Related**:

1. [Saving a plot in Octave with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438777/saving-a-plot-in-octave-with-transparent-background)
2. [Printing / saving a plot as a png file with an alpha channel issue in Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927098/printing-saving-a-plot-as-a-png-file-with-an-alpha-channel-issue-in-octave)
3. http://mlab.no/blog/2014/06/image-transparency-overlay-with-gnu-octave-using-ycbcr/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving a plot in Octave with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438777/saving-a-plot-in-octave-with-transparent-background)

Comment: No. As linked in my question, that does not work, at least for me.

Comment: as far as I know, proper transparency handling throughout is a feature that was still being worked on until recently. I think this may possibly work in the about-to-be-released version 6. but this was definitely not the case for 5.1.0. However, there are many ways to achieve that effect with a bit of extra effort (e.g. produce the layers you want, and then combine externally with imagemagick, or a gimp script, etc).

Comment: (this is my own anecdotal experience btw, I'm not an octave developer). But I have made transparent png figures this way many times.

Comment: in fact I answered something similar in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58932458/4183191

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - I know you are not a developer of octave, but you are seasoned in its use.
And I know you have answered that, in fact I have linked the question (I'm not sure you noticed that).
But: 
1) For some unknown reason ImageMagick was not working for me,
2) I suspected there would be a more native way of handling it.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - Besides, I wonder why you say "adding transparency in octave is still not fully supported". I am commenting on that other post.
I solved this below with ver 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `imwrite` option seems to work. First create the image file `img_fname`, then create an alpha layer for it.

It would be interesting to know if one could avoid the intermediate non-transparent file.

**EDIT**:
I managed to create the image directly from my plot, instead of requiring the intermediate file.

```
x = -10:0.1:10;
plot (x, sin (x));
# Print figure directly to image instead of file
im = print(gcf, '-RGBImage');
tcolor = [255 255 255];
alpha(:,:) = 255 * ( 1 - (im(:,:,1) == tcolor(1)) .* (im(:,:,2) == tcolor(2)) .* (im(:,:,3) == tcolor(3)) );
imwrite(im, 'temp.png', 'Alpha', alpha);
```

**Notes**:

1. With a little simple algebra one could add transparency for any number of colors, and any opacity level for each color.
   Moreover, one could move this into a function.
2. The multiplication of `im` and `tcolor` could be possibly vectorized as well.

**Related**:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57664-how-to-add-alpha-channel-to-the-image-and-convert-that-image-into-png-format

Comment: What do you mean by intermediate file? There doesn't seem to be one here.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - I was precisely finishing this point. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Ah yes. That's what I was about to comment too. Saving to RGBA png with imwrite is fine (and well done for spotting it). What is less supported is saving the plot itself directly, and particularly creating _layers_ with transparency. (but, looking more carefully you didn't ask for that anyway).

Comment: The RGBImage switch is a nice find! I was not aware of it. +1 :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - Still have to wrap this up with vectorizing the multiplication of `im` and `tcolor` as well.

Comment: Up to you but I wouldn't complicate this answer more. I think it makes the point nicely as it is. :) The key points are the RGBImage switch, and ability to save with Alpha. Anything beyond that is up to the user really.  (e.g., I would prefer gaussian transparency around the value of interest, like gimp does transparency, otherwise you get those weird outlines where the colour isn't quite white). But I wouldn't do that in the answer here because that would be a distraction.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - Agreed.